# Get key pressed on react native

Tags: react-native

I use React Native to build an app to Android tablet. I plug a physical keyboard on it and I need to get any key pressed.

Example: the user tap the key `F` so the app open the `Function` screen

```
if (screenPress == 'F'){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Function')
}
```

How to do it?

I try to use react-native-key-event

```
KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyCode, event) => {
  listener(keyCode)
  this.setState({busca: keyCode})
});
```

But it's not working

Comment: May be this help you: [react-native-key-event](https://github.com/Yufeikang/react-native-key-event)

Comment: Is the expected scenario an input field or something else? Is your end goal to use key binding as app shortcuts?

Comment: User tap the key "F" on input ?

Comment: not on input. tap 'F' on screen using a physical keyboard

Comment: @MateiRadu my end goal is read a barcode using a reader

Comment: In that case I think that a key event listener like the one suggested by @erkan should do the trick.

Comment: I cant to use the react-native-key-event, can you take me an example? I use: `KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyCode, event) => {listener(keyCode); this.setState({busca: keyCode}) });` but not work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this options suit your case, but there are new lib for a key press handling (developed by me):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-external-keyboard

```
 import {ExternalKeyboardView} from 'react-native-external-keyboard';
  <ExternalKeyboardView
    onKeyDownPress={onKeyDownHandler}
    onKeyUpPress={onKeyUpHandler}
    canBeFocused
  >
```

This question was asked 5 years ago, but maybe new searches can find the solution =)